# Migrating to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I was tasked to research migrating a 2007 MOSS to ShrePoint 2010. Got two servers, one is runing a SQL 2008, and the other has SharePoint 2010 already installed. I need to migrate several publishing and team sites and their corresponding databases. I started reading this article on [Upgrade and Migration for SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214)
, then another at [Migrate an existing server farm to a 64-bit environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd622865%28office.12%29.aspx) but have a little confusion about wheather I'm migrating, upgrading, or moving the system, as each article defines steps to do this.

Current 2007 MOSS and SQL 2005 are on Windows 2003 32-bit OSs. The new system which at this point in not part of the farm but is in the same domain, are a 64-bit blades running Win 2008 OS with SQL 2008 and SharePoint 2010 - all already instaled / Central Admin site already running. The whole farm consists of 2 severs I just described.

Thanks for reading my post and appreciate any pointers!

Risho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through this exact scenario. The documentation on the various methods can get confusing. Note, for simple farms (no BDC, etc.), all you really need is the content databases. Here's a simple way to accomplish your goal:

- On existing, 2007 farm, make sure it's Service Pack 2
- On existing 2007 farm, run `stsadm -o preupgradecheck`
- Fix any errors identified by the upgrade checker
- Backup the Content database(s) you want to migrate (old 2007 farm)
- Restore Content database(s) to new SQL server
- Create a new Web Application on the new 2010 farm. A new WebApp will need to create a Content DB, so name it something like WSS_Content_Temp. **This will be the WebApp that you will restore your Content to, so name the WebApp appropriately**. You'll remove the content DB, so name it whatever you want.
- From PowerShell, run: `Test-SPContentDatabase -name <NameOfMovedContentDB> -webapplication http://yourNewWebApp`
- Fix any errors identified
- From PowerShell, mount the newly restored/moved database. Run `Mount-SPContentDatabases -name <NameOfRestoredContentDB> -webapplication http://yourNewWebApp`. You should see a progress % number that is incrementing. Depending on how big your content databases are, this could take a while (30+ minutes)
- From Central Admin -> Application Management, select/highlight your new Web Application.
- The go back to Central Admin -> Manage Content Databases, and remove the original, temp Content DB (WSS_Content_Temp)

At this point, if all went well, you should be able to browse to http://yourNewWebApp and see all your content.

Rinse and repeat as needed.

Comment: thanks for the info. I ran pre upgrade check and it returned three failed test including OSPrerequisite, which in my case is non issue. A PendingUpgrade failure -  I'm guessing no issue again, and UnsupportedSqlServerVersion - again no issue. However, got several messages "Aborted due to internal error". I ran the configuration wizard sucessfully after which I re-run the upgrade check but the same results. Although, this on the test farm. The production farm yielded much better results. Same three failures and only one Aborted message on ModifiedWebConfigWorkflowAuthorizedTypesInfo.

Comment: Luckily, with this method, since you're just working from a backup, you wont' do any real harm. If you hose the WebApp, or it errors out really bad, just delete the WebApp and restored database, and try again. Also, if you're so obliged, please mark as answer : )

Comment: Actually I've go couple clarifications. When you say "Backup the Content database(s) you want to migrate (old 2007 farm)" do you  mean via central administartion/Ops/Perform a Backup or in SQL manager?

Comment: I mean run a SQL-based backup - from SQL Mgmt Studio. Make sure you run a Full backup. Then, on the new SQL Server, from Mgmt Studio, do a Restore operation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. The test revealed 16 errors such as "MissigFeature", MissingSetupFile, and MissingWebPart. There are several custom coded webparts that I did, most with data feed from SQL. I Thought I could just restore it anyway and deal with the webarts later, but it didn't turned out that way. The Mount command filed, as you might imagine, with the log file indicating 6 errors and 25 warnings. The errors refer to features that were not installed. Warning are for other custom webparts as well. Not sure where to go from here....

Comment: When I get those erros, I just go through each error, and systematically fix each one. Just Google each error,a nd fix from there. A pain, but has to be done.